# Unable to install ref-struct module on nodejs 12.14.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, ref-struct

i am trying to install ref-struct module using following command :

```
npm install ref-struct
```

Environment specification :

nodejs : **12.14.0**

npm : **6.13.4**

Error i am getting error :

[image]

[image]

Output as text in above screenshots.

C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode>npm install ref-struct

> ref@1.3.5 install C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref
>   node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\np
m-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\no
de-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  binding.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(222): error C2661: 'v8::Value::BooleanValue': no overloaded function takes 0 argum
ents [C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(253): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Uint32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [C
:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(2611): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Uint32Value' (compiling source
   file ..\src\binding.cc)
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(360): error C2664: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(const v8::String::Utf8Value &
)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local' to 'const v8::String::Utf8Value &' [C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\bui
ld\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(360): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::Local' to 'const v8::Str
  ing::Utf8Value'
  c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(360): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
  conversion, or the operator cannot be called
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(447): error C2664: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(const v8::String::Utf8Value &
)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local' to 'const v8::String::Utf8Value &' [C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\bui
ld\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(447): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'v8::Local' to 'const v8::Str
  ing::Utf8Value'
  c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(447): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
  conversion, or the operator cannot be called
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(521): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Uint32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [C
:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(2611): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Uint32Value' (compiling source
   file ..\src\binding.cc)
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(550): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Uint32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [C
:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(2611): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Uint32Value' (compiling source
   file ..\src\binding.cc)
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(582): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(583): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(584): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(585): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(586): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(587): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(588): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(589): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(590): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(591): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(593): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(594): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(595): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(596): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(597): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(598): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(599): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(600): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(601): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(602): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(603): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(604): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(605): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(606): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(608): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(615): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(616): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(617): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(618): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(619): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(620): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(621): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(622): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(623): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(624): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(625): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(626): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(627): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(628): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(629): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(630): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(631): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(632): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(633): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(634): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(635): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(636): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(637): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(638): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(641): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(642): warning C4996: 'v8::Object::Set': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser
\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.14.0\include\node\v8.h(3402): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Set'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(643): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser\D
esktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(117): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\src\binding.cc(644): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\testuser\D
esktop\testnode\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\testuser\desktop\testnode\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(117): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebui
ld"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\testnode\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ref@1.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@1.3.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-19T04_26_36_677Z-debug.log

**How can i resolve this issue ?**

Comment: Kindly don`t post images of code/error instead copy paste them here so that we can debug it easily and also refer to this [ask].

Comment: I'd suggest to report this to the developer(s) of `ref-struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref isn't compatible with the latest node.js versions, due to last update was 4 years ago.
Downgrading to node.js v10.17.0, or use ref-napi instead of it.
**npm i ref-napi**